# Cannot get button to toggle a change in pygame

Tags: python, button, pygame, transition

I am wondering why it is that my "GO" button will not toggle the

```
def game_start()
```

permanently, it toggles it while holding the button, but when you let go of the button its goes back to the main menu?

I am also curious to if there is a way of making the text and buttons vanish when
you press the go button as the game has start?

I am quite new to python so an explanation would be great with any code I have made a mistake on and or need to add/change.

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]

#Colours
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,200,0)
red = (200,0,0)
green_bright = (0,255,0)
red_bright = (255,0,0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

#Pictures
road = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\John\Desktop\Michael\V'Room External\1.png")
BackgroundPNG = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\John\Desktop\Michael\V'Room External\BackgroundPNG.png")
carImg = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\John\Desktop\Michael\V'Room External\Sp1.png").convert_alpha()


pygame.display.set_caption("Broom! || BETA::00.0.3")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_intro():
    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        print(mouse)
        print(click)

        screen.fill(blue)
        screen.blit(BackgroundPNG,(0,0))

        largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("V'Room!", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        #Button
        if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green_bright,(75,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                print("GO == 1 ! == None")
                x = 350
                y = 370
                game_start()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(75,400,100,50))

        smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("GO", smallText)
        TextRect.center = ((75+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        if 550+100 > mouse[0] > 550 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_bright,(550,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,400,100,50))

        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Exit", smallText)
        TextRect.center = ((550+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))
        screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)

def game_start():
   print("Car Loaded Sucessfully")
   screen.blit(road, (0,0))
   screen.blit(carImg, (350,370))

game_intro()
```

Comment: there is nothing in `game_start` what can keep it toggled. It needs some loop with own `pygame.event.get()`, `screen.blit`, `pygame.display.flip()` etc.

Comment: `pygame.display.flip()` and `pygame.display.update()` are doing almost the same thing - use only one of them.

Comment: the other solution: use variable `game_started = True` instead of function `game_start()` and then use `if game_started:` to draw car in `while intro` loop.

Comment: I have changed it so that it goes down to the 'def game_start():' but it changes intro to false. So the code just keeps skipping down to the game_start and does not keep looping and restarting the main menu. I am not too sure if this is correct. I have tried the game_started True and it game me a black screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of solution is to use `game_started` variable instead of function `game_start()` and use it to decide what to draw - title or car and road, GO or STOP button, etc.

I use rectangles in place of bitmaps to make full working example.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ----

size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]

#Colours

black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,200,0)
red = (200,0,0)
green_bright = (0,255,0)
red_bright = (255,0,0)

# --- functions ---

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def game_intro():

    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
    smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)

    text_vroom, text_vroom_rect = text_objects("V'Room!", largeText)
    text_vroom_rect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))

    text_go, text_go_rect = text_objects("GO", smallText)
    text_go_rect.center = ((75+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    text_stop, text_stop_rect = text_objects("STOP", smallText)
    text_stop_rect.center = ((75+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    text_exit, text_exit_rect = text_objects("Exit", smallText)
    text_exit_rect.center = ((550+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    game_started = False 

    intro = True

    while intro:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        screen.fill(blue)
        #screen.blit(BackgroundPNG,(0,0))


        # road and car - or title

        if game_started:
           screen.blit(road, (0,0))
           screen.blit(carImg, (350,370))
        else:
            screen.blit(text_vroom, text_vroom_rect)

        # Button GO/STOP

        if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green_bright,(75,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                # toggle True/False
                game_started = not game_started
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(75,400,100,50))

        # draw GO or STOP
        if not game_started:
            screen.blit(text_go, text_go_rect)
        else:
            screen.blit(text_stop, text_stop_rect)

        # Button EXIT

        if 550+100 > mouse[0] > 550 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_bright,(550,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,400,100,50))

        screen.blit(text_exit, text_exit_rect)

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(15)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Broom! || BETA::00.0.3")

#Pictures
road = pygame.surface.Surface( size )
road.fill(black)

carImg =  pygame.surface.Surface( (10,10) )
road.fill(green)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_intro()
```

**EDIT:** second solution is to create function (`game_running`) with own `while` loop, own buttons, etc.

I had to use `pygame.time.wait()` because `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` is not good function for single click on button. Computer (and `while` loop) is too fast (for human click) and `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` toggle button many times. Better to use `pygame.event.get()` for single click.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ----

size = width, height = 720, 480
speed = [2, 2]

#Colours

black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,200,0)
red = (200,0,0)
green_bright = (0,255,0)
red_bright = (255,0,0)

# --- functions ---

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def game_intro():

    text_vroom, text_vroom_rect = text_objects("V'Room!", largeText)
    text_vroom_rect.center = ((width/2),(height/2))

    text_go, text_go_rect = text_objects("GO", smallText)
    text_go_rect.center = ((75+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    text_exit, text_exit_rect = text_objects("Exit", smallText)
    text_exit_rect.center = ((550+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    running = True

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        screen.fill(blue)
        screen.blit(text_vroom, text_vroom_rect)

        # Button GO

        if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green_bright,(75,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                # wait because `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` is too fast for human clik
                pygame.time.wait(100)
                # run game
                game_running()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(75,400,100,50))

        screen.blit(text_go, text_go_rect)

        # Button EXIT

        if 550+100 > mouse[0] > 550 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_bright,(550,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,400,100,50))

        screen.blit(text_exit, text_exit_rect)

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(15)

def game_running():

    text_stop, text_stop_rect = text_objects("STOP", smallText)
    text_stop_rect.center = ((75+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    text_exit, text_exit_rect = text_objects("Exit", smallText)
    text_exit_rect.center = ((550+(100/2)),(400+(50/2)))

    running = True

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        screen.fill(blue)
        #screen.blit(BackgroundPNG,(0,0))


        # road and car - or title

        screen.blit(road, (0,0))
        screen.blit(carImg, (350,370))

        # Button STOP

        if 75+100 > mouse[0] > 75 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green_bright,(75,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                # return to menu
                return
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, green,(75,400,100,50))

        # draw STOP
        screen.blit(text_stop, text_stop_rect)

        # Button EXIT

        if 550+100 > mouse[0] > 550 and 400+50 > mouse[1] > 400:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red_bright,(550,400,100,50))

            if click != None and click[0] == 1:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, red,(550,400,100,50))

        screen.blit(text_exit, text_exit_rect)

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(15)


# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Broom! || BETA::00.0.3")

# pictures
road = pygame.surface.Surface( size )
road.fill(black)

carImg =  pygame.surface.Surface( (10,10) )
road.fill(green)

# fonts
largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',115)
smallText = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf",20)

# others

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

game_intro()
```